# Create a file descriptor

Tags: c, file-descriptor, file-handling, fdopen

I want to create a file descriptor in C whose value i will specify in code.
I have a integer variable which specifies the value of file descriptor to be created. For example i may need a file descriptor whose value is 5 and later associate that with the file named "sample.dat" .

Answer (score 6):

`fd = open ("sample.dat", O_RDONLY);` open the file

`dup2 (fd, 5);` and copy the file descriptor `fd` into the descriptor number 5

now you can do `read (5, buffer, BUFF_MAX);` or also use `fd` to access the same file. You need to close the `fd` explicitly if you do not need it.

As @Arkadiy told see `man dup2` for details.

Comment: `dup` and `dup2` don't close the old file descriptor.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected the error.

Comment: @ChrisLutz From [LDP] (https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html): `NOTES: the old descriptor is closed with dup2()!`, please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

You need dup2()

http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup

Comment: You have to be careful. If `newfd` already belongs to a file it is closed! I think you would be better of using something like a map.